# How to Get Cooperative Achievements in D3

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Can you complete a cooperative achievements in a Public Game by yourself, or must another player be present in the game?

Comment: These are cooperative achievements, so it requires you to cooperate with someone. Otherwise, what's the point of having one achievement for killing Diablo in Inferno and another for killing him in Inferno when playing cooperative?

Comment: @JamesJiao Ty for clearing it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cooperative achievements are only achievable with two or more players depending on the achievement.

I understand that some people enjoy solo achievements more than multiplayer ones, but in this case, you will just have to do the hard yards to get the cooperative ones.